# Use frameworks causes other already imported pods to fail

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods, ios-frameworks, mbprogresshud

Project A, objective C language project has already imported other objective C projects B and C.

MBProgressHUD is used in all A, B and C. So pod "MBProgressHUD" is there in podfile B and podfile C individually as well.

pod install project A works fine with all the things rightly and I am able to reference MBProgressHUD correctly.

First question:
Is it fine to have such an import individually in each project? or pod install ignore automatically when it sees the library already imported in Project A?

Second question:
In Project A now, I have to import a swift based pod D. For what I have learnt so far, I added the "use_frameworks!" and imported the pod using pod "D". As soon as I do this the xcode8.0 that I use, starts complaining MBProgressHUD/MBProgress.h not found as it hits the first pod, B, I am sure it will happen for other pods, if I somehow remove MBProgress from B.

Where am I going wrong and what is the way to fix, I am not getting much help using web search, spent very long hours? I have added MBProgressHUD/MBProgressHUD.h in the ProjectA Bridge header file. Doesnt help.

I am sure someone would have hit this issue.
Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Forgot a semicolon... It's always the semicolon.

Comment: @WillBoland Please if you could elaborate on this?

Comment: Is this about importing the MBProgressHUD.h in the bridge file and ending it by semicolon? If so the problem is not in the root project where I am importing in ProjectA, it is while I build it and it tries to compile and link ProjectB and ProjectC which internally have imported this using #import <MBProgressHUD/MBprogrgressHUD.h>. The failure happens on the pod projects. The documentation is not so great about these issues. One more thing I observed is, with having use_frameworks! is turning all my static library projects pods marked as "Dynamic library", which is surely a wrong setting.

Comment: Ah, understood now.